# Adding/print values (columns names) if a certain values appears in specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey I'm very new to python and using it for data organizing
I have a dataframe that resembles this:

```
   Sample ID  A  B  C  D  E
0             0  0  2  9  1
1             0  3  0  9  0
2             0  0  0 10  0
3             4  0  0 10  1
4             0  3  0 10  1
```

And would like to fil out the 'Sample ID' with the corresponding column name (except column D) when there appears an specific number. So it would look like this:

```
   Sample ID  A  B  C  D  E
0     C + E   0  0  2  9  1
1         B   0  3  0  9  0
2             0  0  0 10  0
3     A + E   4  0  0 10  1
4     B + E   0  3  0 10  1
```

I have quite large data frame with 126 rows and 13 columns that resembles this. And have all different combinations of the numbers.

I have used If-Else conditions on multiple columns but with no real success. Is there a efficient way to do this? I saw a similar problem in "print columns names if row equal to value in python", but fail to see the logic of making it certain columns and values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names without `D` and `Sample ID` with separator `+`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Sample ID','D'], sort=False)
df['Sample ID'] = df[cols].ne(0).dot(cols + ' + ').str[:-3]
print (df)
  Sample ID  A  B  C   D  E
0     C + E  0  0  2   9  1
1         B  0  3  0   9  0
2            0  0  0  10  0
3     A + E  4  0  0  10  1
4     B + E  0  3  0  10  1
```

Comment: @Goku - No, this question was deleted one or two hours ago, so answered already, but cannot post.

Comment: Good... By the way I admire some of the guys on SO. You are one of them:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using a mask to get the appropriate column names for each row:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Sample ID','D'], sort=False)
mask = df[cols].gt(0).values
df['Sample ID'] = [' + '.join(cols[x]) for x in mask]
```

Output for your sample data:

```
  Sample ID  A  B  C   D  E
0     C + E  0  0  2   9  1
1         B  0  3  0   9  0
2            0  0  0  10  0
3     A + E  4  0  0  10  1
4     B + E  0  3  0  10  1
```